# Adding a typical error bar into the key not into the data points in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I do not have error values for all my data. So instead of putting error bars into data points I want to add information about the mean error as a horizontal line (they are x axis errors, I do not have for y axis) into the corner of the plot like scales of maps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an arrow with bar heads which uses the same line style like your data points:

```
set style arrow 1 heads size char 0.5,90 lt 1
error_len = 1
set arrow from first 1,graph 0.95 rto first error_len,graph 0 arrowstyle 1
plot 'data.dat' lt 1
```

You must only tweak the arrow position and the error size.

You could use the `stats` command (since 4.6) to extract the x-values from your data to get an easier positioning of the error bar:

```
set style arrow 1 heads size char 0.5,90 lt 1
error_len = 1
stats 'data.dat' 
set arrow from first 0.98*STATS_max_x,graph 0.95 rto first -error_len,graph 0 arrowstyle 1
plot 'data.dat' lt 1
```

Comment: The first method worked very well. Thank you so much!